# Curl of a vector field Vs rotation

Tags: vector-fields

$$yi+xj$$
Curl of above vector field is $1-1=0$. I thought this means if we put an object in the vector field, it wouldn't rotate. However if I put an object on $y$ axis at say $(0,5)$, it will rotate clockwise because the velocity is increasing with $y$. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: It will never return to the same position. In that sense it won't rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl (like grad and div) are **local** properties which means that if you put a small cross in a fluid without curl then it will not rotate about its centre.

On the other hand the global motion of the cross (which moves with fixed orientation) in the fluid is pretty much unconstrained by the vanishing curl so the centre of the cross can definitely move around in lines that encircle the origin.

See https://www.falstad.com/vector/ and select the 2d visualisation with curl crosses to see the point.

Comment: Anywhere on $y$ axis, the vector field is $yi+0j$. This has curl $1$ right?

Comment: You must evaluate the derivative before fixing the value of x=0

Comment: Haha ok but still the picture is confusing me. You said curl is a **local** property. That means it refers to the *spin* of the cross, not the global motion of its center. But in $y$ direction, say at $(0,5)$, the vector field at bottom is less and top is more. So if I put a cross anywhere on $y$ axis it would definitely spin?

Comment: In some sense the curl is measuring exactly how much more or less the magnitude of the vector is at the top or bottom (in your words) over an infinitesimal distance, $dy$. The curl tells you that to first order in $dy$ that difference is zero, hence no rotation!

Comment: See the site I linked to.

Comment: Thanks @lux it's helpful visualizing. If I understand correctly it seems the $x$ component of field $yi$ will make the cross spin *clockwise*, but then the surrounding $y$ components of the field $xj$ make it spin *counterclockwise*.  Both effects balance and the cross wouldn't spin. Feels I'm oversimplifying.. See anything wrong?

Comment: This seems to be confusing. If the vector field is curl-free and it has no (topological) holes, then I would say that the motion will not make a circle around origin (=will not make a closed loop). Not sure what "move around in lines that encircle the origin" means.

Comment: @pooja that's fine - to first order those effects balance out and you have no local rotating of the crosses about the centre. Peter Franek you are confusing the local rotating (that curl describes) with the global motion that may or may not involve closed loops that return to their starting point. Curl does not describe the latter and your comment below the question is making precisely this mistake.

Comment: @lux I wrote, "if it has no (topological) holes". In that sense, my claim is, I believe true, and easily follows from Stokes theorem (for instance). Only if topology is nontrivial, you get a difference between local and global in this fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately not the case. How could the curl of a function evaluated at one point contain information about the global "circulation" or whatever you want to call it. Please see the animations in the link:  it's possible to have non zero curl and no global circulation

Comment: And the other way around